# Multiple configurations for a task in my build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm using [this](http://openbakery.org/gradle.php) awesome Gradle plugin to compile my iOS projet.

According to the documentation my build.gradle looks like this :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url('http://openbakery.org/repository/')
    }
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath group: 'org.openbakery', name: 'xcodePlugin', version: '0.9.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'xcode'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '1.12'
}


xcodebuild {
  workspace = 'WORKSPACE'
  sdk = 'iphoneos'
  target = 'TARGET'

  signing {
    mobileProvisionURI = 'URI'
    certificateURI = 'URI'
    certificatePassword = 'PASSWORD'
  }
  scheme = 'SCHEME'
  configuration = 'CONFIGURATION'
}
```

How can I manage multiple configurations for my xcodebuild task ?
I would like something like

```
...
xcodebuild-staging {
      workspace = 'STAGING_WORKSPACE'
      sdk = 'iphoneos'
      target = 'STAGING_TARGET'

      signing {
        mobileProvisionURI = 'URI'
        certificateURI = 'URI'
        certificatePassword = 'STAGING_PASSWORD'
      }
      scheme = 'STAGING_SCHEME'
      configuration = 'STAGING_CONFIGURATION'
    }

xcodebuild-production {
      workspace = 'PRODUCTION_WORKSPACE'
      sdk = 'iphoneos'
      target = 'PRODUCTION_TARGET'

      signing {
        mobileProvisionURI = 'PRODUCTION_URI'
        certificateURI = 'PRODUCTION_URI'
        certificatePassword = 'PRODUCTION_PASSWORD'
      }
      scheme = 'PRODUCTION_SCHEME'
      configuration = 'PRODUCTION_CONFIGURATION'
    }
...
```

I tried multiple things : create a new task that calls xcodebuild.execute() or extend xcodebuild. None of them worked like I wanted to.
I ended having different build.gradle files...

Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick investigation of the source it seems that, what You need is impossible (and it seems a bit strange - such a plugin should enable user to build multiple schemes). I suggest You to contact with the author.

Comment: Ok I understand what you suggest. But I have different Build Settings for each scheme. I really need to change all the signing block for a specific scheme.
Isn't it something I can do in gradle ? Creating multiple configurations ?

Comment: I suppose that even if You create different configuration You still need to build them all. And that's impossible with this plugin. In general it works this way - You create different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible! Have you tried adding the task type as a property? something like...

```
task xcodebuild-staging (type: org.openbakery.XcodeBuildTask) {
  workspace = 'STAGING_WORKSPACE'
  sdk = 'iphoneos'
  target = 'STAGING_TARGET'

  signing {
    mobileProvisionURI = 'URI'
    certificateURI = 'URI'
    certificatePassword = 'STAGING_PASSWORD'
  }
  scheme = 'STAGING_SCHEME'
  configuration = 'STAGING_CONFIGURATION'
}

task xcodebuild-production (type: org.openbakery.XcodeBuildTask){
  workspace = 'PRODUCTION_WORKSPACE'
  sdk = 'iphoneos'
  target = 'PRODUCTION_TARGET'

  signing {
    mobileProvisionURI = 'PRODUCTION_URI'
    certificateURI = 'PRODUCTION_URI'
    certificatePassword = 'PRODUCTION_PASSWORD'
  }
  scheme = 'PRODUCTION_SCHEME'
  configuration = 'PRODUCTION_CONFIGURATION'
}
```

It is dependent on how the plugin is written but you can override tasks like this as long as there is not significant config supplied by the plugin. I have found that plugins can also be extended https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#custom_plugins
but that's more complex.